# How to handle the GCM push message in android?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I am working on GCM implementation.

I Have GCMIntentService class. Whenever there is a push message this class will receive a callback to onHandleIntent method(). How can I access the UI from this class. Or else I have to post notification and I have to write my logic when the notification clicked.

How to handle the push message. My requirement is like I have to start tracking whenever there is a command received "Start". I have received the command from GCM. But I dont what is the proper way to handle it.

How do I handle the received command when the app is not open. And How to find that the App is open or quit?

Please help me on this.

Comment: where is your GCMIntentService class. ?

Comment: Do u need the code along with my question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Handler in GCMIntentService to send callback to UI and send data like below

```
Message _broadCastReply = new Message();
            Bundle _receiverData = new Bundle();
            _receiverData.putString("Receiver", "xyz");
            _receiverData.putString("Status", "abc");
            _receiverData.putBoolean("isError", false);
            _broadCastReply.setData(_receiverData);
            _handler.sendMessage(_broadCastReply);
```

here _handler will be the object passed in the constructor on GCMIntentService

Comment: How do I handle the same when the app is not open. And How to find that the App is open or quit?

Comment: You need to reopen the activity onResume for already open application. else it will call the onCreate when application is quit